# Create real-time report using ZoomData (visualization problems)

Tags: java, javascript, post, reporting, visualization

I'm trying to create simple real-time report using **ZoomData**.
I create DataSource (Upload API) in ZoomData admin interface & add visualization to it (vertical bars).
Also I disable else visualizations for this DS.

My DS has 2 fields:

```
timestamp - ATTRIBUTE
count - INTEGER AVG
```

In visualization

```
group by: timestamp
group by sort: count
y axis: count avg
colors: count avg
```

Every second i send post request to zoomdata server to add info in DS.
I do it from java (also trying to send from postman).

My problem is: data came from post and added to DS but visualization properties become to default

```
group by sort: volume
y axis: volume
colors: volume
```

but **group by stay timestamp**

I can't understand why visualization properties always change after data came in POST request.

Comment: What version of the software are you running? Also which environment- linux or container? You need to upgrade your server to the latest version as this issue was resolved. Email support@zoomdata.com to upgrade.

Comment: ubuntu - 14.04, Zoomdata Server v 1.4.4. rev 08291650